# 'Mobile first' image loading for Wordpress sider

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive-design, slider

All the image slider plugins I have used so far for Wordpress sites have had no way, as far as I could tell, to swap out different sized images at various screen sizes to enable an 'mobile first' experience.

For example: http://www.akqa.com/

They have changed which image is displayed depending on certain breakpoints and it allows control over which part of the image is displayed.

If there is no plugin to automate this, could it at least be achieved through CSS alone?

Thank you

Comment: question is not clear please attached image that what you want or give example link

Comment: I did actually include an example link in the original post, which is http://www.akqa.com/ Please let me know if you need further explanation after seeing this example. I have not solved this yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by HTML  [picture tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture)  or Jquery [.data()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/)

**Jquery Example**

```js
orignalImg = $(".test").attr("src"); // get orignal image
mobileImg = $(".test").data("mobile"); // get mobile image
brakpoint = 768; //what ever your brakpoint

//do magic
function changeImg() {
  $(".test").each(function() {
    if ($(window).width() <= brakpoint) {
      $(this).attr("src", mobileImg);
    }else {
      $(this).attr("src", orignalImg);
    }
  });
}
// call magic
changeImg();

//change image if viewport change
$(window).on('resize', function() {
  changeImg()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Resize your window </h1>
<img class="test" src="http://placehold.it/600x300" data-mobile="http://placehold.it/300x600">
```

**HTML Example**

```
<picture>
 <source srcset="http://placehold.it/600x300" media="(min-width:768px)">
 <img src="http://placehold.it/300x600" alt="img">
</picture>
```

In your [example link](http://www.akqa.com/) they are also using this  `<picture>` tag. This is a simple solution but might be you will face [browser compatibility issue](http://caniuse.com/#search=picture)

Comment: for your WordPress solution i found this use full link https://css-tricks.com/hassle-free-responsive-images-for-wordpress/